# Can a script tag at the end of the body tag act on forms?

Tags: javascript, html

My website needs to have a form that automatically submits, sending the user (with POST data) to an external website. Previously, I was using HTML like this:

```
<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form name='form1' method='post' action='externalwebsite.com'>
      <input type='hidden' name='cartId' value='1337'>
      <input type='hidden' name='currency' value='USD'>
      <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='9'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this resulted in a long delay between the page loading and the form being submitted, as the `onload` event fires very late in the page lifecycle.

Javascript libraries have the `domready` event, to allow code to before the `onload` event fires, but still at a point where it is safe to manipulate the DOM tree. For instance, with the Mootools library, I could do this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

However, I don't want to include a bulky javascript library for such a simple page. As such, I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body>
    <form name='form1' method='post' action='externalwebsite.com'>
      <input type='hidden' name='cartId' value='1337'>
      <input type='hidden' name='currency' value='USD'>
      <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='9'>
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>document.forms[0].submit()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Will this always work, across all browsers? Or should I use a different method?

Comment: Should work fine, just place the script tag inside body.
Are you doing this on a seperate page, i assume the user performs some action to get send to this page that posts them to the next page? You could just create a form on the first page and post it directly, thereby removing any delay.

Comment: @MickHansen The example I've posted here is more simple than the actual form. Its for a payment system that sends the user to an external site to pay. The form has to include lots of fields depending on the users selection and on server-side settings, so it's not possible to go direct as you suggest, unfortunately.

Comment: So what do you currently, parse the form serverside? If you can do it serverside you should be able to do it client-side :)

Comment: @MickHansen I could do it client-side with javascript, but it would be lots more complex as I'd have to insert stuff into the javascript based on changing server settings and I... couldn't be bothered to do that. :)

Comment: Hehe, i get it - Although the smoother the feel for the user the better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the script before closing body tag

```
<html>
  <head></head>  
  <body>
    <form name='form1' method='post' action='externalwebsite.com'>
      <input type='hidden' name='cartId' value='1337'>
      <input type='hidden' name='currency' value='USD'>
      <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='9'>
    </form>
  <script type='text/javascript'>document.forms[0].submit()</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whoops, transcription error on my part - this is what I initially had. Will this always work?

Comment: yes you can access the dom at end of the document in any browser. but it is better to do the post in server side and load the completed form to user rather than doing post request when page load.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Not an option if it's a post to a 3rd party site and the user needs a cookie from the 3rd party (which seems likely since it looks to be a shoppingcart-ssytem)

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not possible to do that as the external site is quite complex, and has a chain of pages of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work (unless JavaScript is disabled) and will be executed as soon as the HTML is loaded into browser. It will not wait for images, scripts etc. to load, as in case of your `onload` solution.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The way you have it now, it won't work. You have to have your code before the closing `</body>` element, or it won't be executed after the page has fully loaded. Once you've done that, then</s> yes, it should work cross-browser.